# Is there a way to add page numbers in libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I was wondering how one can add page numbers in LibreOffice Writer and have that option added to the toolbar?

I have found the answer here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers but those instructions dont do anything at all, let alone help me to add the option to the toolbar for quick access.

Answer (score 0):

The way I personally do it is two step process: insert header first, insert page number field. As the naming suggests that you open the <kbd>Insert</kbd> menu first, select <kbd>Header</kbd> with default style. Next come back to <kbd>Insert</kbd> , and with cursor blinking inside the header, select <kbd>Fields</kbd> and then <kbd>Page Number</kbd>

[image]

A bit faster way is through shortcuts : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>. All that just performs what was described above, without using mouse

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Customize. Then select Insert in the Category column. In the Commands column, go down and select Page Number. Click Add, then Close and click OK.

[image]

Now, you should see that an icon has been added to the tool bar (Second from the left, between New Document and Open Document icons):

[image]